# Random - nextInt(int y) isn't able to give me 18 even integers in a row when 'int y' % 2 == 0 && 'int y' != a power of 2

Tags: java

sorry for that title but I wanted to pack as much information about my problem in as little space as possible without being too confusing.

So, I have a loop which runs **n** times and each time it uses a = r.nextInt(int **y**); to generate an int and if all **n** integers generated are even numbers, then the program "returns true".

The weird thing is: if I chose **n** to be 18 or higher while **y** is and even number which is not a power of 2, then the programm will not "termintate successfully".

I love to help you help me, and can take a heavy dose of criticism.
(I know I'm asking about the Random/nextInt(int) topic but I will also take tips for better coding)

**EDIT:** I looked into the Documentation for Java8 befor I posted here and for powers of two the method uses a different way of producing the random number.

> What I don't understand is why is 18 the breakpoint for consecutive even numbers and why does it work with odd numbers for nextInt(int)?

So the following code will work with `howManyInts =  16` or `17` but not `18 (or higher)` when `nextIntValue` is an even number which is not a power of two `(6,10,12...)`

**It works with howManyInts = 25 and nextIntValue = 8 in less than 20 seconds**

```
import java.util.*;

class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean win = false;
    int areEven = 0;
    long loopCounter = 0; // The loopCounter is used to control the maximum number of loops should be run incase the loop is endless
    int howManyInts = 18;  
    int nextIntValue = 6; // nextIntValue = 6 or 10 won't work while all powers of 2 work fine
                          // also, I don't want an odd value as that would change to odds towards odd values...

    while(win == false){

        loopCounter += 1;
        areEven = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] num = new int[howManyInts];


        for(int a = 0; a < num.length; a++){
            num[a] = r.nextInt(nextIntValue);

            if(num[a] % 2 == 0){
                areEven += 1;
            }
        }

        if(areEven == num.length || loopCounter >= 10000000){
            win = true;
            System.out.println("It took " + loopCounter + " loops to get " + num.length + " random values which are all even.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon There's nothing wrong with posting the OP's code for him in his question, but you shouldn't correct or change it (I saw what you did there).

Comment: @AndyTurner - Sadly changing it to `int nextIntValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;` still never finds `18` even numbers.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon isn't that because there are still roughly the same proportion of odd vs even numbers in the ranges `[0..6)` and `[0..Integer.MAX_VALUE)`?

Comment: Interesting. The code hangs every time `nexIntValue` is even, starting at 6.

Comment: @AndyTurner - Yes but I am still puzzled as to why `18`?

Comment: Well in theory, the odds of getting 18 even numbers in a row is .5^18 or 1 in 262144... you can't really expect to succeed with those odds

Comment: @CalvinP it doesn't matter, it should be around twice as hard as getting 17.
But it seems like it's impossible to get the 18th one out.

Comment: @CalvinP. It even works with 25 when I use a different value for nextInt(int)

Comment: Hmm after running it myself a few times, that does seem strange. I put a `System.out.println(loopCounter);` to see how many times it was executing and see that it easily gets into the millions without a single successful run. I'm about to grab some food, so I'll let it run and see if it ever gets a solution (or out of memory error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use `SecureRandom` instead of `Random`, your program will finish fairly quickly.

Another way would be to use `nextDouble` instead

```
num[a] = (int) (r.nextDouble() * nextIntValue);
```

---

The problem with `Random.nextInt(int n)` is I believe hidden within its implementation and you can read about it in its javadoc.

> The algorithm is slightly tricky. It rejects values that would result
>   in an uneven distribution (due to the fact that 2^31 is not divisible
>   by n). The probability of a value being rejected depends on n. The
>   worst case is n=2^30+1, for which the probability of a reject is 1/2,
>   and the expected number of iterations before the loop terminates is 2.
>   The algorithm treats the case where n is a power of two specially: it
>   returns the correct number of high-order bits from the underlying
>   pseudo-random number generator. In the absence of special treatment,
>   the correct number of low-order bits would be returned. Linear
>   congruential pseudo-random number generators such as the one
>   implemented by this class are known to have short periods in the
>   sequence of values of their low-order bits. Thus, this special case
>   greatly increases the length of the sequence of values returned by
>   successive calls to this method if n is a small power of two.

The implementation looks like this:

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
    if (n <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

    if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
        return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

    int bits, val;
    do {
        bits = next(31);
        val = bits % n;
    } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
    return val;
}
```

While the `next` method looks like this (I've replaced the constants with literals)

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
    oldseed = seed.get();
    nextseed = (oldseed * 0x5DEECE66DL + 0xBL) & ((1L << 48) - 1);
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

(I suppose that `48-31 == 17` is purely coincidental)

Comment: Interesting! Note that changing it to `int nextIntValue = 16384;` (i.e. a power of two) and therefore avoiding the strange loop and the `18` barrier disappears. I've pushed it up to `28` and all works fine.

Comment: @MrChocodemon Random's `nextInt` implementation tries to prevent uneven distribution (which true randomness shouldn't prevent) and the while loop basically corrects this distribution by skipping certain values.

Comment: @radoh So if I understand correctly this happens because (2^31)/6 is not divisble. But why does it work with n = 5 or = 7 ?

Comment: @MrChocodemon Well, what do you mean "it works"? The period/cycles are just set differently, that's all. Also keep in mind that 5 and 7 can choose from more even numbers than odd (for *5*: *3* out of *5* are even, that's radically changing the odds compared to choosing from *6* numbers)

Comment: @radoh Yes I know that uneven numbers would favor one side, but i can use them without them ever failing the while loop. If I use 6 the loop is endless as it will never gibe me 18 even numbers in a row. I can understand why powers of 2 work (because of the different algorythm) but why do certain numbers not produce 18(or more) consecutive even numbers? Why can I use 5 and not 6. What is the logic behind that? What is the mathematical explanation which states which numbers produce which pattern and have which limitations?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question!

I have added some statistic-gathering to the code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class J {
    static Random r = new Random();

    private static class Stats {
        long s[];
        public Stats(int n) { this.s = new long[n]; }
        public String toString()  {
            return Arrays.toString(s);
        }
    }

    public static void test(int target, int options) {
        boolean win = false;
        Stats s = new Stats(target);
        for (long iterations = 0; !win; iterations ++) {
            int even = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < target; i++) {
                if ((r.nextInt(options) % 2) != 0) {
                    s.s[i] ++;
                    break;
                } else {
                    even ++;
                }
            }

            if (even == target) {
                win = true;
                System.out.println(
                    "It took " + iterations + " loops to get " + target
                    + " random values which are all even. Stats: " + s);
            } else if (iterations >= 1E8) {
                win = true;
                System.out.println(iterations + ": " + s);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        test(Integer.parseInt(args[0]), Integer.parseInt(args[1]));        
    }
}
```

The code now ends if no sequence is found after 100M tries; and always stores how far it managed to get before failing (= drawing an odd number).

These are some runs:

```
18 9: It took 57235 loops to get 18 random values which are all even. Stats: [25401, 14081, 7864, 4328, 2508, 1366, 747, 390, 263, 126, 76, 38, 28, 4, 8, 4, 2, 1]
18 8: It took 48612 loops to get 18 random values which are all even. Stats: [24285, 12336, 6066, 2981, 1436, 738, 385, 197, 95, 43, 23, 10, 8, 7, 1, 0, 0, 1]
18 7: It took 23302 loops to get 18 random values which are all even. Stats: [10062, 5712, 3174, 1877, 1101, 590, 331, 190, 98, 59, 44, 31, 18, 8, 5, 2, 0, 0]
18 6: Aborted after 100000000 tries: [49997688, 24993911, 12503043, 6272129, 3113557, 1544194, 788879, 393680, 205236, 89264, 45016, 35858, 5340, 9155, 763, 1525, 0, 763]
```

So, for those particular values (100M attempts at runs of 18 even numbers, throwing 6-sided dice), there were 0 cases where the run bailed out because of the 17th number, but 763(!) where it bailed out because of the last number!

It definitely looks like a higher-quality PRNG is needed, such as the one mentioned by @radoh.

Probabilistically speaking, you would expect to find runs of N even throws of a fair coin with probability 1/(2^N); and you would expect to collect stats where each entry would be 1/2 the previous one. Encountering 0, 763 indicates a strong bias.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is almost certainly with `r.nextInt(nextIntValue);`. Here you are requesting a random integer between `0` and `5`. I cannot understand specifically why `18` is the break point but the chances a sequence of random positive integers less than a small number to be all even must reduce as the limit reduces.

I note that increasing that value from `6` to `100` still does not find length-`18` even sequences. Perhaps the algorithm behind the scenes somehow influences the statistics.

Comment: I know that if i used nextInt(2) the chance per int should be 0.5 or 50%. So the (mathematically real) chance of 18 in a row is 1/(2^18). But when I run it with 25 consecutive even numbers and nextInt(2) the program finishes with: `It took 34201091 loops to get 25 random values which are all even. [Finished in 17.7s]`

Comment: @MrChocodemon - Looks like radoh has a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the random generator doesn't allow 18 consecutive even numbers, when your maxRandom is even, starting at 6.

I changed the code a bit to demonstrate how the 18th random is **always** odd:

```
class NextIntWeirdness {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int maxRandom = 6;

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int evenNumbers = 17;
            int evenResults;
            do {
                evenResults = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < evenNumbers; j++) {
                    int num = r.nextInt(maxRandom);
                    if (num % 2 != 0) {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        evenResults++;
                    }
                }
            } while (evenResults < evenNumbers);

            System.out.println(r.nextInt(maxRandom));
        }
    }
}
```